# Is there a way to export the battery/network usage chart in android studio?

Tags: performance, android-studio, charts, export, performance-testing

I am developing an android app and i know that it is possible to track the battery and network usage with the Profiler within Andorid Studio.

I would like to export the charts or the data of these charts to insert them into a presentation.

Is there a way to export these data o the charts? 
(Taking a screenshot isn't looking fine.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way, the chart is built in Android Studio, not the app. You should probably create your own chart. I suggest using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), one with [Battery Level data](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring) and the other one with [OkHttp Interceptors data](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) (if you're using OkHttp)